# How to create a new JSP project in Eclipse using Maven and Jetty

Tags: eclipse, jsp, web-applications, jetty, maven-3

I'm new to a number of technologies which I need to use together in a project. I have installed a Jetty plugin for eclipse and also got maven3 working with it.

I want to start a new web-app project from scratch which will use JSP, but I want it to follow the conventions for Maven projects.

I already know JSP so learning that isn't the challenge here, just getting the project set up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the tutorial here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_and_Maven_HelloWorld

The only difference in terms of what you want really is that instead of index.html in that example, you would use .jsp and the tags there you wish to use respectively.

The usage of maven, servlets and jetty would still be pretty much identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check this out in the morning(it's hope time now) and hopefully it does what it says on the tin.